# How to use various selectors in SIFR 3r436

Tags: javascript, css, flash, sifr, font-replacement

sIFR.replace(neutra, {
      selector: '#nav li',
      css:[ 'a { color: #ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-size:14px} a:hover { color: #d75a60; text-decoration:underline;}'],
      wmode: 'transparent', preventWrap: true ,forceWidth: true ,fitExactly: true ,forceSingleLine: true ,offsetTop: 0 ,offsetLeft: 0 ,tuneWidth: 0 ,tuneHeight: 0,
    });

and i need to style a `b` inside a `span` inside a `div` ... and i just can't find the way, if i add another sIFR.replace(blah... it won't work, it messes with the other replacement sometimes :S any good reference? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're having trouble with two separate .replace declarations, but in any case, I belive you can chain them within a single declaration using a comma, like this:

```
sIFR.replace(neutra, {
  selector: '#nav li, div span b',
  css:[ 'a { color: #ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-size:14px} a:hover { color: #d75a60; text-decoration:underline;}'],
  wmode: 'transparent', preventWrap: true ,forceWidth: true ,fitExactly: true ,forceSingleLine: true ,offsetTop: 0 ,offsetLeft: 0 ,tuneWidth: 0 ,tuneHeight: 0,
});
```

Comment: yup but i need the "div span b" to be styled with the same font, but different size/color, which's the right way to do it? as i stated if i use another "sIFR.replace(neutra,{...." for this, it just messes up the other declaration i have :S

Comment: If, then, the two declarations are interfering with each other, you'll need to be more specific about targetting one of them so that they don't intersect.  Can you apply a class to the 'div span b' object and target 'div.myclas span b', or somesuch.  Sounds like you need to clearly differentiate one from the other.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, i actually resolved this using

```
sIFR.replace(myfont, {
selector: '#right-column h1',
css: [ '.sIFR-root {color: #921c22;}' ]
});
```

the `.sIFR-root` was the key!